# Google Map takes VERY long to download tiles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm having problems with tile downloading in a Google map, with `angular-google-maps`.

HTTP requests go off as soon as I scroll or zoom, and the download takes milliseconds, but **the TIME-TO-FIRST-BYTE delay can go up to several seconds** as if the socket was queued for something, somewhere.

- Rest of site functionality is not affected by the problem
- Map has around 250 objects (markers, polygons, etc)
- Map is computationally responsive, interaction is fast
- Removal of these objects seems to eliminate the problem

A specific client of mine sent a video where it took **THREE MINUTES** for the tiles to draw on the map. Again, the rest of the site works.

I can reproduce the problem on a smaller time-scale. It's somehow related to objects on the map, but I can't figure out how. What should I do to fix or diagnose this better?

Comment: The maps object where are stored? and the maps is a satellite map? or an  imageTyped map?

Comment: Satellite, objects are stored in an array

Comment: Are you using marker clustering? Also, can you post a code snippet or fiddel which helps repro this?